# Replacing a ListFragment shows the previous list on top of the new one

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-listfragment

I have a ListFragment in one of my views, I make a selection in the list and and I replace that fragment with another list. I then again make another selection in this list that replaces this list with another list but that third list always shows on top of the original list like it was never replaced, why would this happen, can I not go three levels deep when replacing fragments?

here is the layout of the view

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent" 
android:orientation="horizontal">


<fragment
    android:id="@+id/frameOne"
    android:name="com.tyczj.bowling.BowlersListFragment"
    android:layout_width="300dp"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="@drawable/list_background_holo" />

<fragment android:name="com.tyczj.bowling.BowlerEntryFrag"
    android:id="@+id/frameTwo"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

`frameOne` is the fragment that always gets replaced

an Item in the list is selected and I call to replace the list with a new one

```
ft.replace(R.id.frameOne, infoLf).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

then another selection is made in that list so I replace it again like so

```
ListFragment mBowlersBall = new BowlersBallList(bowlerID);
ft.replace(R.id.frameOne, mBowlersBall);
ft.addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

and that is when it shows the two lists together like this

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You aren't properly replacing the fragments.
First of all the documentation for the [`FragmentTransaction.replace()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/FragmentTransaction.html#replace%28int,%20android.app.Fragment,%20java.lang.String%29) method is pretty clear and it states that the `id` supplied to it should be the `id` of the *the container whose fragment(s) are to be replaced* and not the `id` of the `Fragment` to be replaced like you do.

Second, you're mixing static fragments(declared in the xml layout) with dynamic ones(which are added at runtime), which you shouldn't be doing. If you're going to replace that `Fragment` you'll need to declare that `Fragment` in code and not in the xml layout(see [this response](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543770/android-fragment-not-replacing-properly) from one of the Android engineers regarding this matter).

So, instead of the `frameOne` `Fragment` insert a wrapper layout(like a `FrameLayout` for example) with an `id`. In the `onCreate` method you'll add your initial `Fragment`(`BowlersListFragment`) and then, based on a selection in that `Fragment`, you'll replace it by giving to the `FragmentTransaction.replace()` method the `id` of the wrapper layout and the new `Fragment` instance.

Comment: At one point I did have it set up where the xml had frames where the fragments would go but if you hit te back button the fragments would get removed and you would have a blank screen and you would have to hit the back button again to leave the activity. I tried getting around that by checking the number of added fragments in the backstack and calling finish on the activity when there are only 2 fragments left but if I call finish on my activity that starts when you run the app, the `google now` screen shows up instead of the home screen

Comment: @tyczj I hope you didn't added the initial fragment with `addToBackStack()` set, because in this case Android will exhibit the behavior you mention. So, add the initial `Fragments` in the `onCreate` **without** `addToBackStack`.