# Why the fragments conflicts each other during tab navigation or screen rotation in android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-fragments

I have 3 tabs in an activity works fine. but when I navigate from one tab to another, the previous tab contents views in the current tabs. I couldn't figure out what the problem is? I don't get error messages on LogCat and no redFlags. Can someone help me to solve this problem?

The display looks like this:
[image]

Comment: post your xml of the activity with the fragments

Comment: Post your code for your TabListener.

Comment: what about the xml i asked for?

Comment: Where is the code for you CustomTabListener?  How are you switching out the fragments?

Comment: sorry I'm adding the xml and CustomTabListener now

Answer (score 0):

I've seen this where I've added fragments instead of replacing them.  Take a look at your TabListener.  This works for me:

```
    class MyTabsListener implements ActionBar.TabListener {
    private Fragment fragment;


    public MyTabsListener(ListFragment fragment) {
        this.fragment = fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onTabSelected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putInt("Tab", tab.getPosition());
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ft.replace(android.R.id.content, fragment);;    
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabUnselected(Tab tab, FragmentTransaction ft) {

        // Clear the backstack if another Tab is selected
        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fm = getSupportFragmentManager();
            if (fm.getBackStackEntryCount()>0) {
                fm.popBackStack(fm.getBackStackEntryAt(0).getName(), FragmentManager.POP_BACK_STACK_INCLUSIVE);
            }
            ft.remove(fragment);
        }           
    }


    @Override
    public void onTabReselected(Tab tab,FragmentTransaction ft) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub      
    }       
}
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want dynamic fragments you cannot declare fragments statically in your xml, you need a placeholder such as a frame and then replace your fragments with that frame

for example

```
<FrameLayout
      android:id="@+id/map"
      android:layout_width="match_parent"
      android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

and in your activity

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
Fragment fragment = new NearMeFragment();
ft.replace(R.id.map, fragment).commit();
```

check this link from a question I asked a while back

[Replacing a ListFragment shows the previous list on top of the new one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13215400/replacing-a-listfragment-shows-the-previous-list-on-top-of-the-new-one)

also you are calling `ft.add(android.R.id.content,mFragment, mTag);` which is adding a fragment right on top of each other

Comment: I've another tab xml like this: **<ExpandableListView
        android:id="@+id/expandableListView1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:padding="3dp">
    </ExpandableListView>**  How could I transfer this?

Comment: it should be in a fragment, you need a fragment for each tab and replace each fragment when each tab is pressed