# Disappearing Fragments (Dettached without request)

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a simple layout, which contains two fragments. One of the two fragments periodically will replace itself, the other one will remain consistent for the whole time I am using it. For some reason, removing/adding it works just fine, but replacing it causes the other fragment to disappear. I know from debug code that the Fragment simply gets detached, for no apparent reason. Why might this be? If I use the latter, I have to be extremely careful to ensure that the QuestionArea is gone first...

These lines of code come from the in the FragmentActivity class.

```
        fragManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.QuestionArea, getQuestionPostView(), "QuestionArea")
        .commit();

        fragManager.beginTransaction()
        .remove(fragManager.findFragmentById(R.id.QuestionArea))
        .add(R.id.QuestionArea, getQuestionPostView(), "QuestionArea")
        .commit();
```

Here is what I hope is the other relevant code:

XML of the main display:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pearsonartphoto.FontFitTextView
        android:id="@+id/Name"
        style="@style/bigText"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Instructions"
        style="@style/medText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/PowerName"
        />

    <fragment
        android:name="com.pearsonartphoto.NumberDisplay"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/QuestionArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Instructions"/>

    <fragment
        android:name="com.pearsonartphoto.AbstractAnswerFragment"
        android:id="@+id/AnswerArea"
        style="@style/bigText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionArea"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="530sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Part of FragmentActivity which sets up the AnswerArea

```
protected void setAnswerPad(AbstractAnswerFragment pad)
{
    fragManager.beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.AnswerArea, pad, "AnswerArea")
        .commit();
    fragManager.executePendingTransactions();

    answerPadToAnswer=pad.getAnswerKey();
}
```

First time (From FragmentActivity) that the QuestionArea is set.

```
    fragManager.beginTransaction()
    .replace(R.id.QuestionArea, getQuestionPreView(), "QuestionArea")
    .commit();
```

The functions getPostView() and getPreView()

```
@Override
Fragment getQuestionPreView() {
    NumberDisplay display=(NumberDisplay)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.QuestionArea);
    display.setNumber(-1);
    return display;
}

@Override
Fragment getQuestionPostView() {
    NumberDisplay display=(NumberDisplay)manager.findFragmentById(R.id.QuestionArea);
    display.setNumber(answer);
    return display;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problems, most likely, come from trying to change static fragments(fragments declared in the xml layout) at runtime, which you shouldn't do. If you plan to replace, remove etc those fragments in your `FragmentActivity` you should put instead a wrapper layout(like a `FrameLayout`) in their places in the xml layout and use that container for future fragment transactions. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9543770/android-fragment-not-replacing-properly/9543862#9543862) answer from one of the Android engineers.

Comment: This provided the key bit of information that I needed to figure this out. Thanks! I'm going to post a more detailed version for future users, but still, I couldn't have come up with this without your help!

Comment: I've just got to give you one more praise. This fixed in one swoop a ton of problems that I've been facing for a while. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

There were a few things that needed to be done to make this work:

1. The key thing was to change my main XML code to `FrameLayout`.
2. I had to create some of the smaller fragments, when I wasn't having to create them before.

New main XML code:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <com.pearsonartphoto.FontFitTextView
        android:id="@+id/PowerName"
        style="@style/bigText"
        android:background="@color/blue"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"/>

    <TextView android:id="@+id/Instructions"
        style="@style/medText"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/PowerName"
        />

    <FrameLayout 
        android:gravity="center"
        android:id="@+id/QuestionArea"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/Instructions"/>

    <FrameLayout 
        android:id="@+id/AnswerArea"
        style="@style/bigText"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_below="@+id/QuestionArea"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="530sp"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```